# tell cucumber how to use camelCase

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, cucumber, camelcasing

I am using Maven and cucumber in test automation. 
How can I use camelCase while writing my codes as cucumber is using snakeCase by default. 
Is there a way to manage it in pom.xml file in maven?

btw, my IDE is VS Code.

Tnx

Comment: What do you mean by it is using snake_case by default? Using snake_case in what? Auto generated code?

Comment: Do you mean in the step definitions? Could you add some examples/screenshots in order to understand your question .. ? What version of Cucumber  you are using?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `cucumber-junit` you can add `@CucumberOptions` to your JUnit4 runner class.

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions.SnippetType.CAMELCASE;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(snippets = CAMELCASE)
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

You can also create a `cucumber.properties` file in `src/test/resources` containg:

```
cucumber.snippet-type=camelcase
```

If you're using `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` this file should be name `junit-platform.properties`.

Comment: What version of cucumber-junit?
We are running 1.2.4 and the IDE does not recognize the CAMELCASE import.

Answer (score 1):

The step definitions are using snake case rather than camel case. We just need to tell Cucumber that's what we want:

java -cp "jars/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main -p pretty --snippets camelcase features

Now when we run ./cucumber it generates snippets with method names that conform t the Java standard

from The Cucumber for Java book

Comment: Tnx. I was also reading exactly the same book a couple of days ago. The problem with this explanation is, in the book you mentioned, the writer is using Cucumber Command Line to execute codes but I am using Maven to build and run my project.